# Why can't I forward-declare a class in a namespace using double colons?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
class Namespace::Class;
```

Why do I have to do this?:

```
namespace Namespace {
    class Class;
}
```

Using VC++ 8.0, the compiler issues:

> error C2653: 'Namespace' : is not a class or namespace name

I assume that the problem here is that the compiler cannot tell whether `Namespace` is a class or a namespace?  But why does this matter since it's just a forward declaration?

Is there another way to forward-declare a class defined in some namespace?  The syntax above feels like I'm "reopening" the namespace and extending its definition.  What if `Class` were not actually defined in `Namespace`?  Would this result in an error at some point?

Comment: Let me disagree with all answers here, and say it's merely a design bug of the language. They could think better.

Comment: This is tending towards a discussion of why this is illegal in C++ (which is subjective), and it's looking argumentative.  Voting to close.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that in `A::B` the `A` is a namespace identifier instead of a class name?

Comment: @STingRaySC:  The discussion is subjective in that there isn't a clear answer why C++ does this, so we're speculating.  (The question is a shotgun question, with some questions with objective answers, which have been answered already.)  At that point, I become sensitive to traces of argument, and your agreement with Pavel that this is a misfeature of C++ qualifies.  I'd have no problem with a question of why it matters if `Namespace` is a class or namespace.  Just don't get anywhere near the hint of a possibility of conceivably starting a language flame war over syntax.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Because you can't. In C++ language fully-qualified names are only used to refer to *existing* (i.e. previously declared) entities. They can't be used to introduce *new* entities.

And you *are* in fact "reopening" the namespace to declare new entities. If the class `Class` is later defined as a member of different namespace - it is a completely different class that has nothing to do with the one you declared here.

Once you get to the point of *defining* the pre-declared class, you don't need to "reopen" the namespace again. You can define it in the global namespace (or any namespace enclosing your `Namespace`) as

```
class Namespace::Class {
  /* whatever */
};
```

Since you are referring to an entity that has already been declared in namespace `Namespace`, you can use qualified name `Namespace::Class`.

Comment: @STingRaySC: The only way to forward-declare a nested class is to put the declaration inside the *definition* of the enclosing class. And there's indeed no way to forward-declare the nested class before the definition of the enclosing class.

Comment: @STingRaySC: A nested class can be fwd declared -- see my answer.

Comment: @John Dibling: *Nested class* is a class declared inside another class. A class declared immediately inside a namespace is not a nested class. There's nothing about sensted classes in your answer.

Answer (score 204):

You're getting correct answers, let me just try re-wording:

`class Namespace::Class;`

> Why do I have to do this?

You have to do this because the term `Namespace::Class` is telling the compiler:

> ...OK, compiler.  Go find the
>   namespace named Namespace, and within
>   that refer to the class named Class.

But the compiler doesn't know what you're talking about because it doesn't know any namespace named `Namespace`.  Even if there were a namespace named `Namespace`, as in:

```
namespace Namespace
{
};

class Namespace::Class;
```

it still wouldn't work, because you can't declare a class within a namespace from outside that namespace.  You have to be in the namespace.

So, you can in fact forward declare a class within a namespace.  Just do this:

```
namespace Namespace
{
    class Class;
};
```

Comment: All other answers were confusing to me but this "you can't declare a class within a namespace from outside that namespace. You have to be in the namespace." was very helpful hint to remember.

Answer (score 20):

I suppose it's for the same reason you cannot declare nested namespaces in one go like this:

```
namespace Company::Communications::Sockets {
}
```

and you have to do this:

```
namespace Company {
  namespace Communications {
    namespace Sockets {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not actually an answer explaining why you cannot do it.

Comment: This is an answer which saved great amount of my time

Comment: C++17 adds this.

Comment: Here you know that all are namespaces. But with class Company::Communications::Socket you don't know if Communications is a namespace or a class (where socket is the nested class).

Answer (score 13):

It would not be clear what a forward declared variable's type actually is. The forward declaration `class Namespace::Class;` could mean

```
namespace Namespace {
  class Class;
}
```

or

```
class Namespace {
public:
  class Class;
};
```

Comment: Isn't it [impossible to forward-declare a class that's embedded into a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021809/2932052)?

Comment: I think this is one of the best answers, because it answers why this can not easily determined by the compiler itself.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of excellent answers about the rationale involved in disallowing it. I just want to provide the boring standardese clause the specifically prohibits it. This holds true for C++17 (n4659).

The paragraph in question is [[class.name]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.name#2):

> A declaration consisting solely of *class-key identifier*; is either a
>   redeclaration of the name in the current scope or a forward
>   declaration of the identifier as a class name. It introduces the class
>   name into the current scope.

The above defines what constitutes a forward declaration (or redclaration of a class). Essentially, it must be one of `class identifier;`, `struct identifier;` or `union identifier;` where *identifer* is the common lexical definition in [[lex.name]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.name):

> ```
> identifier:
>   identifier-nondigit
>   identifier identifier-nondigit
>   identifier digit
> identifier-nondigit:
>   nondigit
>   universal-character-name
> nondigit: one of
>   a b c d e f g h i j k l m
>   n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>   A B C D E F G H I J K L M
>   N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z _
> digit: one of
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

Which is the production of the common scheme `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` we are all familiar with. As you can see, this precludes `class foo::bar;` from being a valid forward declaration, because `foo::bar` is not an identifier. It's a fully qualified name, something different.