# May I use a constant number to choose a class at compile time, possibly using templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

Let's say I have a constant value (possibly of some enum type).
Let's say I have many classes A, B, D, etc.

Can I have something like this?

```
C<1> anInstanceOfA; //This will be of type A
C<2> anInstanceOfB; //This will be of type B
C<3> anInstanceOfD; //This will be of type D
```

So, is it possible to select a class based on a constant number at compile time?

The general problem is that I am trying to select a functor based on a table, in which the index is an enum. I would like to avoid polymorfism if possible.

**Edit:** For this project I cannot use C++11, thanks anyway to who answered in that context, very interesting to know anyway.
**Edit 2:** In general I can have more than 2 target classes, I have edited my question

Comment: Maybe read up on the "factory pattern"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the LSP and plain C++98:

```
template <int N> class C;
template <> class C<1> : public A {};
template <> class C<2> : public B {};
template <> class C<3> : public D {};

C<1> anInstanceOfA;
```

Since public inheritance in C++ satisfies the IS-A rule, `anInstanceOfA` both IS-A `C<1>` object and IS_AN `A` object.

Comment: You speak a different language :) but indeed this solution is very elegant! A couple of links for my use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle ... and, I cannot find anything about IS-A...

Comment: To get it compiling I add to add `{}`, obtaining `template <> class C<1> : public A {};`... Correct?

Comment: @Antonio yes that's true.

Comment: @Antonio: In Object-Oriented Programming, one of the recurring design questions is "composition or inheritance"? The simpler terms are `foo HAS-A bar` versus `foo IS-A bar`, and in C++ the distinction is  expressed as members versus base classes.

Comment: @Antonio: It will cease being that elegant as soon as you include a class without default constructor to the picture or need to use any parametrized constructor. You will have to copy whatever constructors you may need into your specializations. 0x499602D2 solution doesn't have this problem. C++11 has elegant solution for this problem fortunately.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't the only way to do this, but I hope acceptable for your purposes:

```
struct A { };
struct B { };

template <int N>
struct choices;

template <>
struct choices<1> { typedef A type; };

template <>
struct choices<2> { typedef B type; };

template <int N>
using C = typename choices<N>::type;
```

---

Update: To do the same without C++11 features, you should make `C` a class with a `typedef` member type equal to the corresponding type alias above:

```
template <int N>
struct C
{
    typedef typename choices<N>::type type;
};

// ...
C<1>::type anInstanceOfA;
C<2>::type anInstanceOfB
```

Comment: Thank you! (+1 of course) In the end I will select MSalters answer as more compact, and because saves the ::type at instantiation

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly simple metafunction:

```
template <int N>
struct C {
  typedef typename std::conditional<N == 1,A,B>::type type;
};
```

You would use this as `C<1>::type foo;`.

If your compiler supports C++11 template aliases, you can simplify to:

```
template <int N>
using C = typename std::conditional<N == 1,A,B>::type;
```

and have your preferred `C<1> foo;` syntax.

In pure C++03, implement `std::conditional` as:

```
template <bool, typename A, typename>
struct conditional {
  typedef A type;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct conditional<false, A, B> {
  typedef B type;
};
```

Comment: You can even nest `std::conditional` to save space. I won't comment on its readability over typing out each typedef seperately.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified (I have now), I cannot use C++11

Comment: @Antonio: `std::conditional` is not exactly hard to write yourself, mind you, nor its implementation relies on any C++11 features.

Comment: @Antonio There's a C++03 implementation of `conditional` for you.

Comment: Boost has something similar, if you don't want to implement this called [`enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html). I believe the syntax is very close to std::conditional.

Comment: @ArunR [Boost actually has `conditional` in the `type_traits` library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/conditional.html).