# C++ Calling an overloaded operator (static) from a member function

Tags: c++

So I was implementing my own Quaternion Class and I ran into a problem I wasn't expecting when calling one of my operator (static) functions from a member function. See function `rotateByVector()`;

```
class Quaternion
{
    public:

        double x, y, z, w;

        Quaternion(double w, double xi, double yj, double zk)
        {
            w = w;
            x = xi;
            y = yj;
            z = zk;
        }

        Quaternion operator +(Quaternion q1, Quaternion q2)
        {
            return Quaternion(q1.w + q2.w, q1.x + q2.x, q1.y + q2.y, q1.z + q2.z);
        }

    Quaternion operator*(Quaternion q1, Quaternion q2)
    {
        return Quaternion(q1.w * q2.w - q1.x * q2.x - q1.y * q2.y - q1.z * q2.z
            , q1.w * q2.x + q1.x * q2.w + q1.y * q2.z - q1.z * q2.y
            , q1.w * q2.y + q1.y * q2.w + q1.z * q2.x - q1.x * q2.z
            , q1.w * q2.z + q1.z * q2.w + q1.x * q2.y - q1.y * q2.x);
    }

    void rotateByVector(double x1, double y1, double z1, double[3] res)
    {
        // want to calculate Hamilton Product
        // res_quaternion = this_quaternion * quaternion_vector(0, x1, y1, z1) * this_conj;
        // return double[3] {res_quaternion.x, res_quaternion.y, res_quaternion.z}

        Quaternion q = Quaternion(0.0f, x1, y1, z1);
        Quaternion r = (*this).operator*() q; //doesn't like it
        Quaternion r = this->operator*(q); //doesn't like it either
        ...
        r = r * this.conj();
        res[0] = r.x;
        res[1] = r.y;
        res[2] = r.z;
    }

}
```

How should I implement the multiplication of `this quaternion` times the one from the parameters times the conjugate of `this quaternion`

I know I know close, but I am definitely missing something.

Comment: `this.conj();` isn't a thing. And where is `operator*()`? Please post real code.

Comment: `(*this).operator*() q` are you trying to multiply your 2 class objects here using the operator overloading??

Comment: You are showing the `+` operator but you are using the `*` operator.  Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Also, you're returning a pointer to a local variable: `return double[3] { r.X, r.Y, r.Z };`.

Comment: And also you're declaring a static operator overload, which is illegal. There's like ten ways in which that code doesn't compile.

Comment: Just a resource why it cannot be static http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894124/why-overloaded-operators-cannot-be-defined-as-static-members-of-a-class

Comment: @all, as usual the downvoting + closing brigade contributes to nothing. Got to love stackoverflow. Removed all the static modified. Now if someone can actually say something constructive, that would actually be useful

Comment: @unixsnob Are you trying to do `r = *this * q`?

Comment: @Sneftel: I need to make some changes to the compiler. Basically calculate the Hamilton Product as per the comment in the function in question.

Comment: Not sure why you think you need to make changes to the compiler in order to do that. Knock yourself out, though.

Comment: @Sneftel /s compiler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when you are overloading you operators in your question you write this ::

`Quaternion operator*(Quaternion q1, Quaternion q2)` Since this is a member function you shall either change it to this

**(1)** `Quaternion operator*(Quaternion q2)`

or possibly use a friend function like

**(2)** `friend Quaternion operator*(Quaternion q1, Quaternion q2)`

So, when you want to multiply your 2 `Quaternion` objects and using the declaration as mentioned in **(1)**, possibly like this ::

```
Quaternion a, b, c;
c = a*b;
```

Your call `a*b` get somehow transformed into `a.operator*(b)` itself so you do not have to explicitly call `Quaternion r = a.operator*(b);` (like i see in your code)
Inside your `operator` function you can access the members of `a` using `this` pointer, since your call to the function `operator*()` get called on object `a`.

That is what operator overloading is meant for! we use the normal operators between objects and not call the functions.

While using the **(2)** declaration, you use a `friend`, a friend is not a member function, but it can access the private data members, so when you use the declaration **(2)** you pass 2 arguments, for both the objects involved in the calculation, Since this time the function is not called on any object!

Further you might consider returning a reference of the object from your operator overload function, this will help you achieve associativity like (a+b+c) kind of thing.

Like changing your declaration to this::

`Quaternion& operator*(Quaternion q2)` or

`friend Quaternion& operator*(Quaternion q1, Quaternion q2)`

Hope this could help!

Try looking into this :: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)
(It explains everything in detail!)

Comment: you mean making the functions return `Quaternion&` ?

Comment: will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks for actually answering the questions, instead of picking holes in it. I wrote the code on the go from some c#. Hence the pointer errors.

Comment: Nevermind!! Well changing the return type won't actually take away your compile errors, also consider changing your statement `Quaternion r = (*this).operator*() q;` to `Quaternion r = (*this) *  q;` if you are trying to multiply the 2 objects!