# Is there a workaround to define a member from inside another namespace?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces

This may seem a bit esoteric, but I have a class structure like this, where a singleton template class is defined in a different namespace than the class actually using it.

```
namespace F{
    template<typename>
    struct Foo{
        static Foo instance;
    };
}

namespace B{
    struct Bar{};
    F::Foo<Bar> F::Foo<Bar>::instance; //error C2888
}
```

Which yields:

```
error C2888: 'Foo<void> Foo<void>::instance' : symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'B'
```

I know that this is how it's supposed to be, but in my instance `Foo` is part of my library and `Bar` is defined by the client, so they won't necessarily be part of the same namespace. The part where `Foo<void>::instance` is defined is part of a macro, so I can hide complexity from the user.

Is there any way that enables me to define the member of a class from inside another namespace?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2060691/241536

Comment: No it is impossible. Just assume two (!) namespaces with a Bar and a F::Foo<Bar>::instance

Comment: objection to the duplicate claim. I know that it doesn't work, I asked for a workaround. Also that solution doesn't solve my problem. I don't even want to declare a class, I only want to define a symbol inside it.

Comment: @DieterLücking could you elaborate? Was that an explanation or a solution?

Comment: If you obect to the closure, you're free to vote to reopen.

Comment: Write another macro to be used in global namespace: `#define IMPL_FOO(T) F::Foo<T> F::Foo<T>::instance;`

Comment: A simple solution for your particular need (assuming that the example code provided is relevant) is to use a Meyers' singleton. Google it. Alternatively you can provide a general definition of the static member in the header file, which works fine due to a special exemption for templates in the ODR.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Oh god yes! Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed! Perhaps I should've asked "How to avoid the need to define an external symbol when implementing a singleton."

Comment: @Cheers: Question reopened.  You can now post that as an answer.

Comment: @downvoter please give a reason for why you downvoted this question. It would really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution for your particular need (assuming that the example code provided is relevant) is to use a [Meyers' singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton), e.g.

```
namespace F{
    template<class>
    struct Foo{
        static auto instance() -> Foo& {
            static Foo the_instance;
            return the_instance;
        }
    };
}
```

Alternatively you can provide a general definition of the static member in the header file, which works fine due to a special exemption for templates in the ODR:

```
namespace F{
    template<class>
    struct Foo{
        static Foo instance;
    };

    template<class Type>
    Foo<Type> Foo<Type>::instance;
}
```

---

**Amendment**:

Here's a concrete example of the last method. It works nicely with g++ 4.8.2 and Visual C++ 12.0 (2013). I can not remember any problem with it with earlier compiler versions.

*main.cpp*

```
auto main() -> int {}
```

*x.h*

```
#pragma once

namespace F{
    template<class>
    struct Foo{
        static Foo instance;
    };

    template<class Type>
    Foo<Type> Foo<Type>::instance;
}
```

*a.cpp*

```
#include "x.h"

#include <iostream>

struct A {};
static bool u = !(std::cout << "A " << &F::Foo<A>::instance << std::endl);

#include "x.h"
```

*a2.cpp*

```
#include "x.h"

#include <iostream>

struct A {};        // Intentionally same as in file "a.cpp"
static bool u = !(std::cout << "A " << &F::Foo<A>::instance << std::endl);
```

*b.cpp*

```
#include "x.h"

#include <iostream>

struct B {};
static bool u = !(std::cout << "B " << &F::Foo<B>::instance << std::endl);
```

Building and running with Visual C++:

```
H:\dev\test\so\0169>cl main.cpp a.cpp a2.cpp b.cpp /Feb
main.cpp
a.cpp
a2.cpp
b.cpp
Generating Code...

H:\dev\test\so\0169>b
A 00988A50
A 00988A50
B 00988A6E

H:\dev\test\so\0169>_
```

Comment: I tried the second one already, but either I did something wrong or MSVC12 doesn't support it. Meyers' singleton is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: @iFreilicht: I agree that if you have to provide access to a common object, then the Meyers' singleton is probably the best of the two possibilities I sketched. Since you had some (unspecified) problem with the direct static member approach, I added a complete concrete example.