# How to deal with namespaces in forward declarations?

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

Hi this is my straight forward question, because i dont know how to explain my question with some example.

Question:

`How to deal with namescpaces in forward declarations where classes are defined in different namespaces?`

if anyone feel this is duplicate of any other question or this is not right way to ask this question means also comment over here. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Maybe you should explain the *problem* you're having with forward-decls in namespaces and update your question accordingly. "How to deal with them" is only slightly less nebulous than "it don't work".

Comment: This question fired to me by one of team met, more over i am new to c++, so only posted directly over here. Along with this i am  studying about namespace now.

Comment: [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059665/why-cant-i-forward-declare-a-class-in-a-namespace-like-this).

Comment: Then ask *them* for the specific problem they're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward-declare the class in the namespace:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    class ForwardDeclaredClass;
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Luchain i understood ur answer now only.