# Forward declaring classes in namespaces

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces, declaration

I was rather surprised to learn that I couldn't forward declare a class from another scope using the scope resolution operator, i.e.

```
class someScope::someClass;
```

Instead, the full declaration has to be used as follows:

```
namespace
{
    class someClass;
}
```

Can someone explain why this is the case?

UPDATE: To clarify, I am asking ***why*** this is the case.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368642/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-forward-declare-a-class-in-a-namespace Technical answer, from that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368642/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-forward-declare-a-class-in-a-namespace/1368738#1368738

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems as though the answer lies in the C++ specification:

> 3.3.5 "Namespace scope" in the standard.
>
> Entities declared in a namespace-body
>   are said to be members of the
>   namespace, and names introduced by
>   these declarations into the
>   declarative region of the namespace
>   are said to be member names of the
>   namespace.
>
> A namespace member can also be
>   referred to after the :: scope
>   resolution operator (5.1) applied to
>   the name of its namespace or the name
>   of a namespace which nominates the
>   member’s namespace in a
>   using-directive;

Answer (score 7):

You can't declare a class outside its namespace, because the compiler could not be aware of the type of **someScope**.

**namespace{ }** is required to declare the existence of namespace, and then, declare **class someClass** into your scope.

Comment: You are not answering my question though, I am asking why this is the case not how to get around it - I already know that. :-)

Comment: IMHO, this decision was choosen to make a distinction between  someClass::someMember and someNamespace::someClass. How could otherwise handle it ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why. Maybe because, in your first code snippet, `someScope` is undeclared. It can be a namespace, or a class name. If someScope is a class name, you can't independently forward declare a class member of another class.