# Declaring in one namespace and Defining in other namespace in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, declaration, qualified-name

Just like we can declare in namespace and define in Global namespace, like this:

```cpp
namespace B{
    void func();
}
void B::func(){
    std::cout<<"abcdef\n";
}
int main(){
    B::func();
}
```

And we have to call it using `B::` because its **declared** in B namespace as per aanswers to [Forward declaring classes in namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279781/).

```cpp
void func();
namespace B{
  void ::func(){

  }
}
using namespace B;
int main(){
  func();
  
}
```

And according to those answers, we can't do this because the compiler won't know where the definition is.

Is it safe to say the "Global namespace is special because compiler always checks it, that's why its safe to define in global namespace."?

Can we do something to make a user-defined namespace as special as the global namespace, or do something to make the compiler aware that the definition is "here!!"?

Comment: what is first and second answers depends on your sorting. It can be different for other user. The one with "the green tick" is the accepted answer. Though also accepted answer can change. Better include links to the answers. Below the answer: Share

Comment: please one question per question. And `>` is for quotes, better only use it for quotes

Answer (score 2):

The global namespace encloses all other user-defined namespaces.

On the other hand, you may define a function declared in a namespace in its enclosing namespace.

From the C++ 20 (9.8.1.2 Namespace member definitions)

> 2 Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that
> namespace by explicit qualification (6.5.3.2) of the name being
> defined, provided that the entity being defined was already declared
> in the namespace and **the definition appears after the point of
> declaration in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s
> namespace**.

The first your program example is correct because the global namespace encloses the namespace B.

The second your program example is not valid because the user-defined namespace B does not enclose the global namespace where the function func is declared.

Here is an example. If you have the following function declaration within the namespace C

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            void f();
        }
    }
}
```

then it may be defined one of the following ways

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            void f();
        }
        void C::f() { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            void f();
        }
    }
    void B::C::f() { /* ... */ }
}
```

or

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            void f();
        }
    }
}
void A::B::C::f() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: _9.1.8.2 NS member defination and example maked it clear !!! Thanks you. I will closely look into the edits and make sure same mistakes wont repeat again